# how to have a list like this

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, data

i would like a list that has one more column with a hyper link "details" inside of it. when i click that link for each list item, it should take me to a new item view. if this is the first visit then the new item template should be empty, otherwise, it should be already filled in with latest saved data and the data should be in edit mode.

```
//this is a sample list
NAME       LAST NAME    UPDATE
jim        jones        details

//after clicking details, this should appear
Address: <textbox> with data (if data is already in db)
Phone: <textbox> with data (if data is already in db)
...
```

how can i do this in sharepoint 2010?

Comment: From where do the users come from? Do you enter them manually or are they the site members or maybe they're migrated/pulled from some other system (i.e. ERP)?

Comment: @AndreyMarkeev Good thought, are these members of the site, or just a list of people?

Comment: users are my site visitors, they are authenticated by windows. that has nothing to do with my question though! all i want is a list of some data that has a link column to new/update records.

Comment: @jim I'm just trying to figure out if those users are already put into a normal SharePoint list, or they reside somewhere else: solution will be very different depending on that.

Comment: the data in my list has nothing to do with actuall users of my site. those are just static information in database(sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the customizations proposed below will take no more than 5 minutes to implement once you know what to do. SharePoint is flexible, though not very user friendly, and sometimes it's just hard to find the correct button or menu item...

Also one more thing: as I understood from your comments, you don't know SharePoint well, so I tried to make the answer as illustrative as possible, and admittedly it is a bit overgrown with images. Nevertheless, ...

Here I assume you have some existing **SharePoint list** with data filled in, something like this:

[image: list of users]

So if you go to list settings (Ribbon -> List Tools -> List -> List Settings) you will see two columns, *Name* and *Last Name*:

[image: list columns]

Add additional columns into this list. As in your question, let's add *Address* and *Phone* as a simple text fields (this will make them appear as text boxes). Make sure the "Add to default view" checkbox is not checked:

[image: add to default view checkbox]

In this case the view will be the same as on the first picture, but if you open view or edit dialog on the list item, you will see there are also Address and Phone fields there:

[image: edit form]

Usually you go to edit form by clicking "Edit" in context menu or by selecting item first, and then clicking "Edit item" on the ribbon:

[image: edit button]

At this point you might want to consider if it is ok for you and stop here.

But if you still want to have a separate column with edit link, you will need to open SharePoint Designer and slightly customize the list.

Navigate to this list under List and Libraries:

[image: List and Libraries]

Then under "Views" group click All Items.

You will see your list view. On ribbon, find "Add/Remove Columns" button. Click it and then add "Edit (edit link)" column to the view:

[image]

The result will be something like this:

[image]

It is very easy to change the title of the column and replace edit icon with some text. For title, click to the title text and then in Properties enter new title enclosed in apostrophes:

[image]

Then, click on edit icon, and below in the status bar select img tag and click Insert HTML:

[image]

Type "Details" instead of default "<>" text. Click accept icon, and then again select edit icon and hit delete. You will get something like this:

[image]

And in browser it will look like this:

[image]

Also if you don't want form to appear in a modal dialog, and prefer to redirect user to a separate page, this can be configured in List Settings, under Advanced Settings -> Dialogs -> Launch forms in dialogs (select "No").

It is also very simple to customize edit form if you want i.e. make "Name" and "Last name" not editable, and anything else. You have to learn SharePoint and practice with SharePoint Designer for few days, and maybe learn a bit of XSLT, but in the end you will be able to create almost any imaginable view and any kind of form for a SharePoint list.

Comment: thank u so much!

Comment: @AnderyMarkeev, Is it possible to make field read only thorough sharepoint designer 2010 only on edit form?

Comment: @Kai, sure it is. Create a custom edit list form in SPD (make it default edit form), select field you want to make readonly, then switch to "Code" tab (left bottom corner of the editor window), and then in XSLT, change ControlMode property for the field control from "Edit" to "Display".

Comment: Oh, know I see... I've tried to do this on existing (OOB) edit form. Thank you, Andrey!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your situation correctly, this is built-in and easy to accomplish. Go to the list in question, click "List Settings" on the ribbon under the List tab, then at the bottom you should see the various views associated with the list (by default it will just be "All Items" - you can create another one from here if you wish and set it to the default view). Click on the view you wish to modify and it will show you all the columns that appear in the view. Some of them will say "(linked to item)", I'm guessing these are the ones that will be helpful to you. When one of these appears in the view, (such as Edit or Company - you can create more columns to fit whatever you need) it will let the user click on it to view the details of the list item. If they have values, they will populate and be editable. If not, they will be blank.

If you need more detailed columns than already exist in the list, you can add them from existing columns (in the list settings), or in the site settings you can create your own.

Does that help answer your question?

**Edit:** Per our discussion... So you have a list like this...
[image]

And when you click the "Modify View" button that I have circled, you don't see something like this?

[image]

Comment: Some of them will say "(linked to item)".... i don't see any column like that. i even searched for such a column in "add new column" inside of list modification page.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking in the settings for the actual view (not the list columns)? The views are listed at the bottom of the list settings page, if you click on the name of one of them you should see what I was referring to. An alternate way to get to it is clicking "Modify View" in the List tab on the ribbon.

Comment: I know where the views are. When u click a view it will take u to design view and in there none of the fields are marked with "linked to item". I tried to add such an column, But no luck!

Comment: Okay, there's something I'm missing then. When you say "design view" do you mean you're doing this in SharePoint Designer, or through the browser? What permissions do you have on the site? What kind of list is this, and how did you create it?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference for me, i can do it in designer or browser, whichever can help me out! The list is created from an excel sheet. Now i want to make it kind of dynamic, so you can add/update/delete the way i mentioned in question

Comment: Check out the edit of my answer, I added some pictures for clarification. Sorry for the barrage of questions, just trying to help out :)